# custimize Pligg to check the traffic per pulblished page

Tags: pligg

I want to customize the my pligg site to track down the traffic per published page , I checked in the database but have not found any such functionality in default pligg.

Is there any module available for this, or if I decide to do it on my own is there any developers documentation for pligg?

I searched this on google but did not find any relevant results had to take stackoverflows help. I am good at PHP and have known pligg in and out(as a user).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know of any functions in Pligg by default.. but let me say you can do this all within Google Analytics. They offer free API tools and I'm pretty sure their analytics code is amazing.

[Here's a quick tutorial](http://www.alexc.me/using-the-google-analytics-api-getting-total-number-of-page-views/74/) which discusses building over the Analytics API and pulling total page views. With this you can then publish on each popular story how many views it's had and store this within your own DB? Or just clear it every day, there are numerous options. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: it worked, thanks a lot , works just as I had thought of ..!!! thank you again ..!!!!